# Can you detect an external battery for phones?

Tags: usb, battery

## Question:

I have a ThermalTake external battery for smartphones, a 8400 mAh one, and I want to detect how much charge is left so I could maybe make an alarm to tell me when it's full.

#### I want to know whether it's possible to detect the current charge through the USB port.

*And maybe some tips to make an alarm with python, but that's secondary (I can just ask/search in stack overflow).*

## Extra information:

Computer:

- HP dv6 Pavilion
- USB 2.0 an 1.0 ports
- Running Lubuntu 16.10
- Thermaltake TriP Portable Power Pack 8400 mAh

Comment: Here's a tip: *only ask on Stack Overflow if you've searched the web, read all Stack Overflow posts twice and tried everything and have a clear problem statement that doesn't include 'write this code for me'*. It might seem like I'm kidding, but I'm not.

Comment: I'm not saying write this code for me, I said that as a secondary question, my main question is stated in bold, and though I forgot to mention `lsusb` doesn't detect the battery as a valid USB device

Comment: Not sure on the situation, is the battery connected through usb, charging?

Comment: It's connected through USB, charging